# Proper method to use keyboard bindings to focus a dynamic menu/sub-menu in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

**The Context**

I am using BlueprintJS to create a custom data-table with type-ahead results which return in a Menu component (think Google Sheets with typeaheads). I would like to be able to use the keyboard arrow keys to navigate through this menu.  I'm able to focus the menu when the ArrowDown key is pressed. Then using a keyboard handler on the Menu, I keep track of the index of the current selected item and highlight it with CSS, quasi-focusing each menu item.

Here is an example of what I'm working with. [Simple Input with Menu](https://codesandbox.io/s/blueprint-js-menu-keyboard-binding-rn5rk?file=/src/App.js)

**The Problem**

First and foremost, this method doesn't actually focus the list item, which destroys any accessibility.  Second, using this method I can't move between submenus since the key handler is only keeping track of the top level elements of the menu.

**Potential idea**

When the list data changes (as it is a dynamic typeahead), create an object of Refs and pass this to the MyMenu function, and create a clever keypress handler, calling ref.current.focus() on each keypress navigation. This would properly focus the list item for accessibility, but not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

**Question**

What would the proper way of handling this? Is there a different component structure I should be thinking about?

Comment: I ended up completely abandoning the submenu idea and made expandable headings, which can then be selected.  Then in each MenuItem, I created a useEffect to call ref.current.focus to let the browser know that the item is focused, in addition to the CSS highlighting.